# React Hooks add/subtract count from click div/list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The problem is that the count needs to be subtracted from the total when the item on the list has been un-selected. So far it works when the item is selected and the count goes up. Maybe some kind of toggle is needed to subtract the total from the count. And if the count is zero it needs to show and empty div with no zero or numbers.  thanks in advance if anyone can help out ‍☠️

Sandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-counter-friday-28-fgp85?file=/src/App.js:0-948

````
export const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center relative -mr-10">
      <div className="absolute top-10 w-240 opacity-100 bg-white -ml-48 shadow-md rounded-lg text-left p-3 z-30">
        <span className="text-center inline-block w-3">
          {selectedMenu.length}
        </span>
        {props.options &&
          props.options.map((option, _idx) => (
            <div key={option.id} className={props.titleAndSubtitleGroup}>
              <div className="flex flex-row">
                <input
                  onClick={() => {
                    !selectedMenu.includes(option) &&
                      setSelectedMenu((oldValue) => [...oldValue, option]);
                  }}
                  type="checkbox"
                  id={option.group}
                  className="bg-white border-2 rounded w-4 h-4 mt-1 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center mr-2 focus-within:border-blue-0"
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor={option.groupId}
                  className={"no-underline hover:underline"}
                >
                  {option.text}{" "}
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownMenu;

import React from "react";
import DropdownMenu from "./DropdownMenu";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <DropdownMenu
      options={[
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "Post",
          icon: "",
          url: "/#",
          group: "01",
          groupId: "01"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "Delete",
          icon: "",
          url: "/#",
          group: "02",
          groupId: "02"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "Forward",
          icon: "",
          url: "/#",
          group: "03",
          groupId: "03"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: "Share",
          icon: "",
          url: "/#",
          group: "04",
          groupId: "04"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          text: "Copy Link",
          icon: "",
          url: "/#",
          group: "05",
          groupId: "05"
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
};
export default App;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't removing elements from the `selectedMenu` array when the checkbox is unchecked.

I suggest using an object instead of an array to store a map of option `id` to checked status. Then get an array of values from the `selectedMenu` state and filter by what is selected to get a derived selected count.

```
const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState({});
```

...

```
<span className="text-center inline-block w-3">
  {Object.values(selectedMenu).filter(Boolean).length}
</span>
```

or to conditionally only display non-zero values (*this OFC can be optimized to be more **DRY***)

```
<span className="text-center inline-block w-3">
  {!!Object.values(selectedMenu).filter(Boolean).length &&
    Object.values(selectedMenu).filter(Boolean).length}
</span>
```

...

```
<input
  onChange={e => {
    const { id, checked } = e.target;
    setSelectedMenu(selected => ({
      ...selected,
      [id]: checked
    }))
  }}
  type="checkbox"
  id={option.group}
  className="bg-white border-2 rounded w-4 h-4 mt-1 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center mr-2 focus-within:border-blue-0"
/>
```

[image: Edit react-hooks-add-subtract-count-from-click-div-list]

OFC, if you wanted, or needed, to keep the array, then just conditionally filter the array, or append a value.

```
<input
  onClick={() => {
    selectedMenu.includes(option.id)
      ? setSelectedMenu((oldValue) =>
          oldValue.filter((val) => val !== option.id)
        )
      : setSelectedMenu((oldValue) => [...oldValue, option.id]);
  }}
  type="checkbox"
  id={option.group}
  className="bg-white border-2 rounded w-4 h-4 mt-1 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center mr-2 focus-within:border-blue-0"
/>
```

Comment: Great solution, how would it be possible  to leave an empty div if the count is zero? To be more precise, the zero needs to be hidden when the count is zero

Comment: @Python-Pirate Standard conditional rendering, i.e. `<div>{!!Object.values(selectedMenu).filter(Boolean).length && /*populated content */}</div>`. I'll update sandbox and solution.